# Jenkins Java compile causes Java crash

Tags: java, compilation, jenkins, gradle, libzip

I've been constantly getting a crash in Java when I try to compile some Java code with Gradle in my Jenkins server. Anyone know any possible solutions? It seems like libzip has some kind of issue...

I'm using a Ubuntu server. Full error report: http://pastebin.com/dnmFTbLg

```
:reobf#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGBUS (0x7) at pc=0x00007f54df18218d, pid=17194, tid=140002619074304
#
# JRE version: 7.0_25-b30
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (23.7-b01 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libzip.so+0x518d]  Java_java_util_zip_ZipFile_getZipMessage+0x114d
#
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/ICBM/hs_err_pid17194.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please include
# instructions on how to reproduce the bug and visit:
#   https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openjdk-7/
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
```

Does anyone know why Java is crashing while trying to perform the compile?

Comment: From the stacktrace it looks like a file can't be found during the `gradle` build - `net.minecraftforge.gradle.tasks.user.reobf.ObfArtifact.applySpecialSource(Ljava/io/File;Ljava/io/File;Ljava/io/File;)`. What is your `gradle` build and what is the command Jenkins is invoking it by? Additionally if you run the same command on the same environment manually do you get the same error?

Comment: The error seems to be caused by a faulty zip implementation which crashes in native code instead of giving you a proper exception. If you google `Java_java_util_zip_ZipFile_getZipMessage+0x114d` you'll find that several people mention invalid zip files or accessing files that are not done yet. I'd try if updating the JDK helps and then check the jars if they are intact, maybe one has evil invalid bytes.

Answer (score 0):

I see you're using OpenJDK. Try to use Oracle JDK instead: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Java

Comment: Rick - did you face the same issue and switching to Oracle JDK helped? Reason I ask - the stack trace shows that a jar is in the process of being retrieved and an attempt is made to traverse the jar causing the stacktrace.